# About short circuit in power supplies

Tags: power-supply, power

Does the constant current mode in power supplies correspond to short circuit?

Comment: Obviously, depends on the individual real-world supply.

Comment: @MarcusMuller, it's far from obvious, let's keep 'condescending' off the forum and put help to the forefront - you don't have to comment :-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be condescending! Leila, I really didn't mean to hurt your feeling, hope that didn't happen. I did want to encourage you to contribute more by adding details on your supply – often, adding such detail can even help finding an answer on your own (and that are my favourite moments – when a question answers itself by a real moment of epiphany on the asker's side :) )

Comment: @MarcusMuller, thanks very much for your follow-up, there's an army of 'em out there who seem to only like sneering at those learning. That's never been you historically and I feel bad for picking you up on it :-) Back to engineering...

Comment: @TonyM seriously, I'd rather have you point me towards my own rudeness than being one of these :) Cheers, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The constant current and constant voltage modes are actually voltage set and current limited modes. if you set it to 5V and 1A, then the power supply will operate such that the voltage is held at 5V as long as the current is less than 1A, but will reduce the voltage if the current exceeds 1A.

Imagine you connect a variable resistor to the output of such a supply, and keep the resistance at 1k. The power supply has a voltage of 5V across it, and draws a current of 5mA - well within the current limit, so the current limit controller does nothing. Now you slowly reduce your variable resistance, and watch the current rise - as long as current <1A the current limiter does nothing.

Say you reach 5.0 Ohms, and the current has just climbed to 1A.
Now if you decrease the resistance a little further, the current will  increase a little beyond 1A, and the current controller will start to reduce the voltage till the current comes back to 1A. So if you reduce R to 4.95ohms, the current will rise to 5V/4.95 Ohms=1.01A, at which point the current control will keep decreasing the voltage till current reaches 1A. This voltage will be 4.95V.

If you dead short the output, the output current will remain 1A, and the voltage will be 1A times the resistance of the shorting wire.

Comment: Assuming OP is talking about bench supplies. Some CC supplies require a minimum voltage output (such as LED drivers) so a short is a different case than constant current (normal) operation.

Comment: I'm confused - you set it to 5V and 1A but then state that it will give 5A at just below 5V - I keep re-reading and it just doen't make sense to me

Comment: @JImDearden i made a mistake with the values- fixed up now.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the constant current mode in power supplies correspond to short circuit?

That depends on what you consider "corresponding to".

A power supply with current limit feature is basically a constant voltage or constant current supply *whichever results in less*.  The intent is for it to be used as a constant voltage supply.  The current limit feature is to prevent damage when the load tries to draw more than the rated current.  The current regulation is usually not as good or accurate as the voltage regulation, since these supply isn't intended for constant current operation when used normally.

A short circuit is certainly one case of the load trying to draw too much.  However, it is not the only case.  A resistive load, for example, can still exceed the current limit but is not a short.

For example, consider a 12 V 1 A supply with current limiting.  If you connect a 12 Ω resistor, it draws 1 A, and all is fine, although right on the edge.  If you connect a second 12 Ω resistor in parallel, then the combination will try to draw 2 A.  The supply won't let it, and goes into current limit mode instead.  Usually the current limit is set a little higher than the maximum current spec.  Let's say the supply actually puts out 1.1 A when in current limit condition.  You have a total of 6 Ω connected to it, so the output voltage will drop to 6.6 V, which is what it takes to not exceed 1.1 A.  No short was needed to make this happen.